# Windows Batch File To Create Folders For Each Date In Year Entered With Support For Leap Years

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch script to create folders for each date for the year entered and for it to know when a leap year is entered. I am not sure how to create the IF conditions so can anyone help me out. Thanks.

```
@ECHO off
ECHO ### Date Folder Generator: Started! ###
SET /p year=### Enter Year [e.g. 2014]:
SET year=%year:,=%
MKDIR %year%
CD %year%
FOR %%G IN (01_January 02_February 03_March 04_April 05_May 06_June 07_July 08_August 09_September 10_October 11_November 12_December) DO MKDIR %%G
CD 01_January
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,31) DO MKDIR %%G-Jan-%year%
CD ..
CD 02_February
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,28) DO MKDIR %%G-Feb-%year%
CD ..
CD 03_March
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,31) DO MKDIR %%G-Mar-%year%
CD ..
CD 04_April
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,30) DO MKDIR %%G-Apr-%year%
CD ..
CD 05_May
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,31) DO MKDIR %%G-May-%year%
CD ..
CD 06_June
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,30) DO MKDIR %%G-Jun-%year%
CD ..
CD 07_July
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,31) DO MKDIR %%G-Jul-%year%
CD ..
CD 08_August
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,31) DO MKDIR %%G-Aug-%year%
CD ..
CD 09_September
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,30) DO MKDIR %%G-Sep-%year%
CD ..
CD 10_October
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,31) DO MKDIR %%G-Oct-%year%
CD ..
CD 11_November
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,30) DO MKDIR %%G-Nov-%year%
CD ..
CD 12_December
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,31) DO MKDIR %%G-Dec-%year%
CD ..
CD ..
ECHO ### Leap Years: 2016 2020 2024 2028 2032 2036 2040 2044 2048 2052 2056 2060 2064 2068 2072 2076 2080 2084 2088 2092 2096 2104 2108 2112 2116 2120 2124 2128 2132 2136 2140 2144 2148 2152 2156 2160 2164 2168 2172 2176 2180 2184 2188 2192 2196 2204 2208 2212 2216 2220 2224 2228 2232 2236 2240 2244 2248 2252 2256 2260 2264 2268 2272 2276 2280 2284 2288 2292 2296 2304 2308 2312 2316 2320 2324 2328 2332 2336 2340 2344 2348 2352 2356 2360 2364 2368 2372 2376 2380 2384 2388 2392 2396 2400
ECHO ### Date Folder Generator: Finished! ###
```

Would also be cool if the FOR loop could be improved to get some of the code repetition out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\years"
SET /p year=### Enter Year [e.g. 2014]:
IF NOT DEFINED year GOTO :EOF 
SET year=%year:,=%
IF %year% lss 100 SET /a year=2000+year
IF %year% gtr 1901 IF %year% lss 2099 GOTO generate
ECHO year entered out of range 1901..2099
GOTO :eof

:generate
MD "%sourcedir%"
SET /a feb=year %% 4
IF %feb%==0 (SET "feb=02,February,29") ELSE (SET "feb=02,February,28")
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
MKDIR %year%
CD %year%
FOR %%a IN ("01,January,31" "%feb%" "03,March,31" "04,April,30" "05,May,31" "06,June,30" "07,July,31" "08,August,31" "09,September,30" "10,October,31" "11,November,30" "12,December,31") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=," %%b IN (%%a) DO (
  SET "month=%%c"
  SET "month=!month:~0,3!"
  MKDIR %%b_%%c
  pushd %%b_%%c
  FOR /l %%q IN (1,1,%%d) DO MD %%q-!month!-%year%
  popd
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

input-year-processing is not bullet-proof, but that's not the object of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Input and validate year
    set /p "year=Enter year (yyyy): " || goto :eof
    set "year=%year:"=%" & rem "
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%year%") do echo ERROR: Bad data & goto :eof
    if "%year:~3,1%"==""   echo ERROR: Too short & goto :eof
    if not "%year:~4%"=="" echo ERROR: Too long  & goto :eof

    for %%f in ( 
        01_January   02_February 03_March    04_April 
        05_May       06_June     07_July     08_August 
        09_September 10_October  11_November 12_December
    ) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%m in ("%%f") do (

        rem Prepare literals
        set "monthName=%%n"
        set "monthShortName=!monthName:~0,3!"

        rem Calculate days in the month and adjust leap years
        set /a "month=1%%m %% 100"
        set /a "days=30+((month+month/8) %% 2)"
        if %%m==02 set /a "days=days - 2 + (3 - year %% 4)/3 - (99 - year %% 100)/99 + (399 - year %% 400)/399"

        rem Folders creation
        for /l %%d in (1 1 !days!) do (
            set "dd=0%%d"
            md %year%\%%f\!dd:~-2!-!monthShortName!-%year% 2>nul
        )
    )
```

Some points

- I've included a very basic year validation.
- Before you ask, the `rem "` is just to get the syntax highlight work as intended because there is a odd quote in the code
- Month length is calculated for all months not only February.

Answer (score 0):

I like both Magoo's and MC ND's answers - they should be quite fast.

There is a very simple solution using [getTimestamp.bat - a hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847) that performs date arithmetic and formatting operations. It is pure script that will run on any Windows machine from XP forward. Full documentation is embedded within getTimestamp.bat.

The one disadvantage of this solution is it is comparatively quite slow because of the overhead in initiating the Windows Script Host (WSH) for each iteration.

I echo each created folder just so you can track the progress.

My script below requires the year be entered as the `%1` argument, as opposed to using SET /P to prompt for a year.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (0 1 365) do (
  call getTimestamp -d "'1/1/%~1'" -od %%N -f "{yyyy}\{mm}_{month}\{dd}-{mth}-{yyyy}" -r dt || exit /b
  if "!dt:~-4!" neq "%~1" exit /b
  md "!dt!"
  echo !dt!
)
```

Comment: EDIT - Oops, forgot to include the link to getTimestamp. All fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another one!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Input and validate year
set /P "input=Enter Year [e.g. 2014]: "
set "year="
set /A year=%input:,=%, yearMOD4=year %% 4 2>NUL
if defined year if !year! geq 2014 if !year! lss 2099 goto continue
echo Error: Bad data
goto :EOF

:continue
rem Generate arrays with month names and number of days
set i=100
for %%a in (January@31 February@28 March@31     April@30   May@31      June@30
            July@31    August@31   September@30 October@31 November@30 December@31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=@" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set "month[!i:~-2!]=%%b"
      set "days[!i:~-2!]=%%c"
   )
)
if %yearMOD4% equ 0 set days[02]=29

rem Generate the folders
md %year%
cd %year%
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set month[') do (
   md %%a_%%b
   for /L %%d in (1,1,!days[%%a]!) do md %%a_%%b\%%d-!month[%%a]:~0,3!-%year%
)
```